# How to get a class of dynamically added content via innerhtml

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch

I am adding content to my HTML through JS by using innerHTML. But now when I try to access a class attached to that content I just get null. How would I access the class?

```
    fetch(url)
        .then((response) => {
            return response.json();
        }).then(data => {
            for (var i=0; i < data['data'].length; i++){
            
            var attributes = data.data[i].attributes,
                title = attributes.title,
                descr = attributes.description,
                author = attributes.author,
                available = attributes.available,
                year = attributes.year,
                id = data.data[i].id;

            var div = document.createElement("div");

            div.innerHTML = `title = ${title}, 
                             descr = ${descr},
                             author = ${author},
                             available = ${available},
                             year = ${year}
                             <button type="button" value="${id}" class="delete">delete</button>`                 

            document.querySelector('.movieList').appendChild(div)
        }
    });

const btns = document.querySelectorAll(".delete");
console.log(btns);
```

I have tried .getElementByClassName, but it also doesn't work :/

Comment: its `.getElementsByClassName` not `.getElementByClassName`

Comment: what's inside "then" will be executed after your top-level code

Answer (score 2):

It's a timing issue.
You need to call querySelectorAll **after** you appended the elements.

Try to put `const btns = document.querySelectorAll(".delete");` right after `document.querySelector('.movieList').appendChild(div)`.

Currently, the moment when you try to find the buttons, they are not there, yet.